Как найти контур пересечения текущей рабочей плоскости с объемным каркасом на основе точек пересечения в C#?
Я решаю задачу построения линии пересечения рабочей плоскости с каркасом (на языке C#), который может быть как плоским, так и объёмным. Если каркас плоский, необходимо строить полилинию, а если объёмный — замкнутый контур пересечения.
На текущем этапе я могу вычислить все точки пересечения рабочей плоскости и треугольников каркаса. Однако возникает проблема: если объемный каркас сложной формы, и пересечение происходит лишь частично, необходимо правильно сгруппировать точки (или какой-либо другой подход), чтобы корректно построить линии или замкнутые контуры пересечения.
Например, в конкретной задаче должно быть построено два отдельных контура в местах пересечения рабочей плоскости и каркаса. Входные данные включают только треугольники каркаса и набор всех точек пересечения.
Какие алгоритмы или подходы можно использовать для решения подобной задачи?


В данном случае видится, что сработает просто последовательная обработка треугольников каркаса по порядку, если они перечислены в порядке следования. Если это не так, то ребра каркаса, несомненно, имеют привязку к треугольникам, и точки пересечения двух ребер одного треугольника дают отрезок, а общее ребро - соединение со следующим.  Возможно, вам пригодятся подходы, используемые в алгоритме Marching cubes (хотя ваши структуры данных отличаются)
